# “Hide Communities“ list should be sorted alphabetically in site name order, not site URL order

Tags: bug, sorting, hidden-communities

In your profile there is a [Hide Communities list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) that lets you configure which communities show up on [your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile). The list displays all the sites you have an account on. It presents their names and it's alphabetically sorted... except it's sorted *by URL,* not by name. This means while most sites appear to follow alphabetical order, some are missing from where you'd expect and instead appear in surprising locations.

For example:

- *Arqade* doesn't appear among the **A**'s where you'd expect to find it. Instead it's at the beginning of the **G**'s, because its URL is `gaming.stackexchange.com`
- *Stack Overflow en Español* is among the **E**'s because its URL is `es.stackoverflow.com`
- *Cross Validated* is among the **S**'s because its URL is `statistics.stackexchange.com`

> [image: arqade] [image: stackoverflow español] [image: cross validated]